# Can I use a query designer to write Linq Queries against a DataSet

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, linq-to-dataset

I've got a DataSet created by the xsd.exe tool to import some xml files, and need to denormalize the data within for display purposes.  Instead of writing linq to dataset queries by hand is there any way I can access the tables within a query builder wizard?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself, but you could take a look at Microsoft's [Visual LINQ Query Builder](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vlinq).  It's a plugin for VS 2008 (*not* Express) and supports C# and VB.NET only.

Comment: I've looked at it, and it appears to be limited to building linq to SQL queries.